# Как сформировать предложение грамотно?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Также обязуемся погасить задолженность по электроэнергии за счет дальнейшего удержания прибыли причитающейся учредителю управления".

Как сделать, чтобы это предложение звучало грамотно и литературно?

Comment: Мне кажется, что правильно в шапке написать "оформить предложение".

Comment: Я бы сказал "сформулировать предложение".

Comment: Ничего себе, и никто меня раньше не поправил!.. Вот так неправильно считал.(( Сотру свой первый комментарий лучше. :)

Comment: Спасибо всем! Расстроился просто своему заблуждению и даже забыл поблагодарить.

Comment: А с Рождеством Вы зря так спешите! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Мы обязуемся также погасить задолженность по электроэнергии - средствами, которые будут получены удержанием части прибыли, отчисляемой учредителю Управления.

Answer (score 0):

Запятую надо поставить перед причастным оборотом

По поводу раздельного написания *за счёт* была дискуссия. Пишется всегда раздельно (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82).

Учредителю, скорее всего, причитается не вся прибыль, а часть ее.

Слово "причитающийся" не соответствует стилистике документа.

Вопрос: что этот учредитель учредил? Организацию под названием Управление? Тогда *Управление* с прописной.

**Также обязуемся погасить задолженность по электроэнергии за счет дальнейшего удержания той части прибыли, которая должна отчисляться учредителю Управления.**

Вопрос о том, почему не просто *удержание*, а *дальнейшее удержание*, оставим автору. Возможно, речь идет о том, что доля учредителя удерживалась и прежде.

Но если слова *дальнейшее удержание* несушественны, то фразу можно упростить:

**Также обязуемся погасить задолженность по электроэнергии за счет той части прибыли, которая должна отчисляться учредителю Управления.**

**Также обязуемся погасить задолженность по электроэнергии за счет доли учредителя в прибыли Управления.**

Comment: По поводу раздельного написания — это же не к автору вопроса. И почему у всех "Управление" с прописной? Разве так принято?

Comment: @grizzly Некто учредил некое управление. Скорее всего то, что он учредил, называется как-то так: Управление сбытом рогов и копыт — и пишется с прописной. Есть другие трактовки?

Comment: Нет, я не уверен. Спасибо за разъяснение. В подобном контексте попадалось только со строчной, как у автора вопроса (в том числе в шаблонах официальных документов). Но раз два опытных участника противоречат моей интуиции, значит она, скорее всего, ошибается.